# How add extra fields data to database with UserCreationForm Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to add data from UserCreationForm extra fields to database, i want to add multiple fields to UserCreationForm and save it to database. I saw other examples from topics here in stackoverflow, but it doesn't work.

Here is a example of my code:
( fields: "agree_terms" or "price" could be anything else)

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm



class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.EmailInput(attrs= 
                                               {'placeholder':'Email'}))
    agree_terms = forms.BooleanField()
    price = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('username', 'password1', 
                                'email','password2','agree_terms','price')
```

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def registers(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        print(form)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,'Conta criada {}'.format(username))
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request,'header-login.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you also changed your `User` model to support those fields? You'd need to add them to the model/table as well.

Although, I wouldn't recommend piling up so much extra data directly on the `User` model.

Comment: No i didn't. I will try that... Thanks